# Store Twig loop for multiple reuse

Tags: for-loop, twig, template-engine

I have two arrays that I loop through, but they are nested.
Reduced to the minimum, it looks like this:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <label>{{ item.name }}</label>

    <select>
    {% for attribute in attributes %}
        <option>{{ attribute.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>

{% endfor %}
```

The problem is the size of the arrays. There are about 1,100 `items` and 400 `attributes`. As one can guess, this is slow. Very slow.

Is it possible to *"store"* the inner loop, and just reuse the generated/rendered block?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I set email information for this question, but got none.
I will try it today after work. I was looking for something like that, but I it looks promising. I'll let you know of that worked for me, later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the inner loop outside of the outer loop and then store the value generated in a Twig variable. Then run the outer loop supplying the variable between the `<select>` tags. This way you only generate the inner loop once.

```
{% set options = '' %}
{% for attribute in attributes %}
    {% set options = options ~ '<option>' ~ attribute.name ~ '</option>' %}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in items %}
    <label>{{ item.name }}</label>
    <select>
        {{ options }}
    </select>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the answer i was looking for.
Two little things I had to change:

`{{ options }}}` one too much curly bracket, an since the var is html code, I had to set the "var" filter:
`{{ options|var }}`.

Comment: doh typo, PhpStorm auto-completes curly braces and I put them in at the same time, fixed.